# CSS Float - 1px Gap Two Pages Exact Same Code

Tags: html, css, css-float

Why am I getting a 1-2 pixel wide gap on http://techmobile.com/contact-usTESTBOX.html between the Search Box and the Right Edge of the Page?

Exact same code for the search box is on http://techmobile.com/open-service-call.html  and this page doesn't have the gap.

I've spent over 2 1/2 hours looking for a solution.

```
#container #search #searchbox_left   { background-image: url("../images/stories/search_left.gif"); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 5px; height: 45px; float: left }
#container #search #searchbox_right   { background-image: url("../images/stories/search_right.gif"); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 6px; height: 45px; float: left }
#container #search #searchbox_area {
float: left;
font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-color: #000000;
height: 33px;
min-width: 410px;
width: auto !important;
width: 410px;
padding: 12px 10px 0px 10px;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: Try looking at `Schedule Virtual Meeting`, comment it out for test. Sorry im just not in position to check it with firebug right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `container` div is a `table` with two rows. The page with extra spaces as two extra `td`s in the second row that are each 1px wide.

```
<div id="container">
<table width="960" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td width="1" valign="top">
<td valign="top" align="left">
<td width="1" valign="top"> </td>
<td width="1" valign="top"> </td>
<td width="1" valign="top">
```

Those bottom cells are the issue as compared to

```
<div id="container">
<table width="960" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td width="1" valign="top">
<td valign="top" align="left">
<td width="1" valign="top">
```

on the page rendering correctly.

**EDIT**

Just to make sure the solutions are clear, either removing the extra `td`s or adding a colspan somewhere on the second to include those extra cells would take care of the spacing.

Answer (score 1):

Mookamafoob's answer is one way to fix the problem, which is with the HTML mark-up rather than the styles: your top row's only column assumes, on both pages, that the second row below it has three columns, with:

```
<td colspan="3" align="right">...</td>
```

Since the "broken" page actually has five columns in the second row, the browser somehow has to deal with them - and since the two extra columns are empty, it just squeezes them into that one or two pixel space you see.  If, for whatever reason, you need to keep the extra two columns in the bottom row on the "broken" page, just change the top row's td's colspan attribute to 5 instead.

Comment: Heh I guess I should have included a suggestion on fixing it, since I pretty much just only pointed out where the issue is. Yes either modifying the colspan or removing the extra cells would take care of it. Good call.

Comment: You can still edit your answer!  Honestly mine should probably have been more of a comment on yours, but weirdly SO's merit system doesn't let me make comments on other people's answers yet.  Which has frustrated me more than once LOL.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 extra cells (<td>) in the subsequent row (<tr>) on http://techmobile.com/contact-usTESTBOX.html:

```
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="1">...</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">...</td>
    <td valign="top" width="1"></td>
    <td valign="top" width="1"></td>
    <td valign="top" width="1">...</td>
  </tr>
```

Two solutions are possible.

**First Solution:** Change the value of colspan in 'search' row/cell from 3 to 5:

```
<td colspan="5" align="right"> ... </td>
```

**Second Solution (*better*):** Delete the 3rd and 4th cells from the subsequent table row:

```
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="1">...</td>
    <td align="left" valign="top">...</td>
    <td valign="top" width="1">...</td>
  </tr>
```

Both work. Choose the one which is most appropriate for your case.

Comment: Excellent! Thank You! Worked just like you said it would